# How can I save different users based on user type using single api in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to save student and teacher information using single POST API. If I choose "student" type the data will be saved in student table. if I choose "teacher" type data will be saved in Teacher table. But the operation will be done by one single API call.

Here is my code:

Model Class: Student

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int s_id;
    @NotNull
    private String s_name;
    @NotNull
    private Date admission_date;
    @ManyToOne
    private Class class_id;
    public int getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }
    public void setS_id(int s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }
    public String getS_name() {
        return s_name;
    }
    public void setS_name(String s_name) {
        this.s_name = s_name;
    }
    public Date getAdmission_date() {
        return admission_date;
    }
    public void setAdmission_date(Date admission_date) {
        this.admission_date = admission_date;
    }
    public Class getClass_id() {
        return class_id;
    }
    public void setClass_id(Class class_id) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
    }
}
```

Model Class: Teacher

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    private int t_id;
    @NotNull
    private String t_name;
    public int getT_id() {
        return t_id;
    }
    public void setT_id(int t_id) {
        this.t_id = t_id;
    }
    public String getT_name() {
        return t_name;
    }
    public void setT_name(String t_name) {
        this.t_name = t_name;
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImplementation implements SchoolService {
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository sp;
    private TeacherRepository tp;

    @Override
    public void save(Student student) {
        sp.save(student);
    
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Teacher teacher) {
       tp.save(teacher);
    
    }

}
```

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class SchoolController {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceImplementation si;

    @PostMapping("/save/{type}")
    public void add(@PathVariable("type") String type) {
        if(type.equals("Student")) {
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Used Gson library to deal with json to java object conversion, Yu will need to send the Student json or Teacher json data to actually save in database along with type

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

@Controller
public class SchoolController {
@Autowired
private ServiceImplementation si;

@PostMapping("/save/{type}")
  public void add(@PathVariable("type") String type, @RequestParam String json ) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if(type.equals("Student")) {
        Student  student = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);
        si.save(student);
    }
    else {
        Teacher teacher = gson.fromJson(json, Teacher.class);
        si.save(teacher);
    }
    
}
```

}